# Route everything through Public IP except SSH on Port 22 through OPEN VPN

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, routing, openvpn, vpn

Is it possible to route a VPS [Ubuntu] SSH service through a OPEN VPN connection but allow ALL other data to exit through the Public address? What sort of iptables magic needs to be done to accomplish this?

SSH data → goes through OPEN VPN
ALL other data → goes through Public

this is my ifconfig details before connecting to vpn

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:32:2a:e6
          inet addr:18x.144.31.77  Bcast:185.144.31.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: 2a03:a0e0:bad:bad::574/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a03:a0e0:bad:bad::573/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a03:a0e0:bad:bad::572/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a03:a0e0:bad:bad::571/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a03:a0e0:bad:bad::570/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe32:2ae6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:73928 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:723 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:4508581 (4.5 MB)  TX bytes:95511 (95.5 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:25 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:25 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:2520 (2.5 KB)  TX bytes:2520 (2.5 KB)
```

after connecting to vpn

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:32:2a:e6
          inet addr:185.144.31.77  Bcast:185.144.31.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: 2a03:a0e0:bad:bad::574/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a03:a0e0:bad:bad::573/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a03:a0e0:bad:bad::572/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a03:a0e0:bad:bad::571/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a03:a0e0:bad:bad::570/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe32:2ae6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3749 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:381 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:282634 (282.6 KB)  TX bytes:60862 (60.8 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.8.2.62  P-t-P:10.8.2.61  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:65 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:62 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:7025 (7.0 KB)  TX bytes:16197 (16.1 KB)
```

Comment: Using a separate network namespace seems to be a bit of overkill. Maybe what you want can be achieved with policy routing? But firsts we must know what is "ssh data". Are those packets originating from `ssh user@some.other.host` commands which your shell users type in? Or are those responses to packets incoming via vpn to your sshd daemon?

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to iptables: Use network namespaces. As root, do something like

```
ip addr show dev tun0
ip netns add vpnssh
ip link set tun0 netns vpnssh
ip netns exec vpnssh su -c 'xterm &' user_name
```

where `tun0` is the network interface of your OpenVPN endpoint and `user_name` the user who runs `ssh`. Note the inet (let's call it `vpn_local_ip`) and peer (`vpn_peer_ip`) addresses for `tun0`.

You now have an xterm where all subprocesses only "see" `tun0` (verify with `ip link`), but unfortunately, moving it set it down. So in this window, use `sudo` to

```
ip link set tun0 up
ip addr add vpn_local_ip peer vpn_peer_ip dev tun0
ip route del default
ip route add default via vpn_local_ip dev tun0
```

You can now run `ssh` in this window, and it will use the OpenVPN connection. Script everything as required (use `ip netns exec vpnssh ...` for the second part).

Comment: thanks for answer but i have missing some information to how replace the variables you are written so i made edit on main question :)

Comment: In your example, the local vpn address ("inet addr") is `10.8.2.62`, and the remote one ("P-t-p" = point-to-point) is `10.8.2.61`. This will likely change with every invocation of OpenVPN. Was that the question?

Comment: i mean what should be replace the variables in your answer according to my information

`user_name = root` ?
`vpn_local_ip = 10.8.2.62` ?
`vpn_peer_ip = 10.8.2.61` ?

note my vpn public ip is fixed 192.71.144.195

Comment: What user do you want to run `ssh` as? That's `user_name`. Yes to the rest. Your public IP does not influence the private network range tunnel IPs, which are the ones you need to route etc.

Comment: ok, i do it but not work :\

this is the steps what i do

Comment: 1. login to ssh by public ip 185.144.31.77
2. write this commands to connect to my openvpn `sudo openvpn --config Sweden-TCP.ovpn`
3.the public ip is timed out now cause i connected to vpn so i login to it again using VPN IP

Comment: 4. write this commands line `ip addr show dev tun0` `ip netns add vpnssh` `ip link set tun0 netns vpnssh` `ip netns exec vpnssh su -c 'xterm &' root`
5. The VPN DISCONNECTED after write this commands so i re connect to vpn using `sudo openvpn --config Sweden-TCP.ovpn`
6.write this commands line `ip link set tun0 up` `ip addr add 10.8.2.62 peer 10.8.2.61 dev tun0` `ip route del default` `ip route add default via 10.8.2.62 dev tun0`